# Query post only from categories that have subcategories

Tags: categories, query-posts

My categories structure :

- Category 1 (8 Posts )

  - subcategory1 (2 Posts)
  - subcategory2 (2 Posts)
  - subcategory3 (2 Posts)
- Category 2 (6 Posts)

  - subcategory1 (2 Posts)
  - subcategory2 (2 Posts)
  - subcategory3 (2 Posts)

I would like to query posts only from the Category 1 (8 posts) and Category 2 (6 Posts) 
without displaying posts from subcategories.

Here's the code sample :

```
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => $cat_slug, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
                $number = 0; ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php 
            $title = the_title('','',false);
            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            echo $title;
            echo $excerpt;
        ?>

<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

How can I edit above code to display posts only from categories 1 ,2 , without displaying posts from subcategories ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tax query with `include_children` set to false:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'your-category-slug',
            'include_children' => false,
        ),
    ),
) );
```